# c# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'

Tags: c#

c# windows form error;
c# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'
please help me out..i tried all possible ways but couldn't fix it

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fname = textBox1.Text;
        string lname = textBox2.Text;
        string username = textBox5.Text;
        string password = textBox6.Text;
        string dob = textBox3.Text;
        string mobile = textBox4.Text;
        string address = richTextBox1.Text;
        string gender="";
        if(radioButton1.Checked){
            gender=radioButton1.Text;
        }else if(radioButton2.Checked){
            gender=radioButton2.Text;
        }else{
            MessageBox.Show("Please select Gender");
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\users\user\My Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\cSharpProject\cSharpProject\CSharpProjectDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        string query = "insert into user values('" + @fname.Trim() + "','" + @lname.Trim() + "','" + @username.Trim() + "','" + @password + "','" + @dob + "','" + @gender + "','" + @mobile.Trim() + "','" + @address + "' ";
        command = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        sda.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        sda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Isn't `user` a reserved word? Check the table name!

Comment: You should remove `@` from all variable names in the query. And read about parameterized queries with C# and SQL [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx)

Comment: you should use sqlparameters :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is a reserve word and thus needs escaping like `insert into [user] values...` Or `insert into "user" values...`

Comment: @"insert into [user] values(NULL,'" + @fname.Trim() + "')  if this null keywork correct?

Comment: user `Identity` column for auto increment id values.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server uses reserved keywords for defining, manipulating, and accessing databases. Reserved keywords are part of the grammar of the Transact-SQL language that is used by SQL Server to parse and understand Transact-SQL statements and batches. Although it is syntactically possible to use SQL Server reserved keywords as identifiers and object names in Transact-SQL scripts, you can do this only by using delimited identifiers.

You can find hte full list here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

In your scenario, if you want to retain the theme you have gone for, then perhaps renaming this to 'Users' or 'UserList' will be best.